# How can I create a menu without links?

Tags: hyperlink

How can I create a menu without links? by java-script !
Such as the following website (in Footer) !
[نمانیدگی تعمیرات بوش و تعمیرگاه مرکزی بوش](http://www.boschcenterco.com/)
http://www.boschcenterco.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to menu and click on menu type and select text separator to crate link without url.

enjoy !